# How do I delete pages from Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I delete pages from a Word 2013 document? I've looked everywhere I can think of, including Page layout and have not been able to figure out how to delete an unwanted page.

Comment: Unless you provide some more insight into the formatting of the proceeding and preceding pages this really isn't answerable.

Comment: [http://blogmines.com/blog/how-to-insert-or-remove-pages-in-word-2013/](http://blogmines.com/blog/how-to-insert-or-remove-pages-in-word-2013/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a big fan of Word, as I don't find it very user-friendly; never-the-less I use it a lot.

If you select the all the content of a page (by clicking & dragging the mouse, for example), then select Delete, the page is deleted. If it is a blank page, I click at the bottom of the previous page (usually the end of the last word), and then click at the beginning of the blank page. That selection spans the "page break." Then selecting Delete will remove the blank page.